# Angular EventEmitter after getting some data from back-end

Tags: angular, asynchronous, eventemitter

I have next code:

```
streets: Street[] = [];
@Output() sendStreets =  new EventEmitter<Street[]>();

triggerLoading(trig: string){
    switch(trig) {
      case 'street': {
        this.loadStreets(this.district);

        //sending data
        this.sendStreets.emit(this.streets);

        this.street = this.building = this.apartment = undefined;
        this.buildings = this.apartments = this.subscribers = [];
        break;
      }
}
```

So the problem is that `this.loadStreets(this.district);` method requests from back-end array of streets and when I send data `this.sendStreets.emit(this.streets);` I get in the parent component empty array in the 1st request, and then in the 2nd one I get data which I should get in the 1st request etc.
So, for example I **SHOULD** get:

> 1 request: "[Str1, St2, St2]", 2request: ["Str10, Str20, Str30"],
>   3request: [Str20, Str30, Str40] etc.

BUT I get: `

> 1request: "[]",  2 request: "[Str1, St2, St2]", 3request: ["Str10,
>   Str20, Str30"] etc.

`

How can I emit it asynchronously, I mean after loadStreet will finish executing I'll emit data?

**UPD:**
How I receive data:

```
<hs-filter> (sendStreets)= "getStreets($event)" </hs-filter >

getStreets(streets: Street[]){
    console.log(streets);
    this.streets = streets;
    this.buildings = this.apartments = [];

    this.streets.forEach(street => {
      this.addresses.push(
        new AddressItem(street.id, 'street', street.title));
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to see how you handle data at receivingcomponent?

Comment: @micronyks plz check update

Comment: do you get required data in `console.log(this.streets);`??

Comment: @micronyks of course not, thats why I'm asking this question here. I get some old data. 1st time I log [], 2nd time Iog data which must be as 1st time data etc

Comment: Do you get data correctly from loadStreets() ?

Comment: @Vega yes, everything is correct in loadStreets

Comment: How do you call triggerLoading()?

Comment: @Vega I call it like: <select  [(ngModel)]="district"  (change)="triggerLoading('street')">

Comment: dos LoadStreet return an observabale?

Comment: @Vega, no this is void function which just calls this.addressService.getStreets(district)
      .subscribe(streets => {
        this.streets = streets;
      });. But addressService.getStreets, ofcourse returns observable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

class EventEmitter extends Subject {
  constructor(isAsync: boolean = false) -
So for your case:
@Output() sendStreets =  new EventEmitter(true);

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem, but I don't like my solution.
If anybody have another one, plz answer

I just moved sendStreets into loadStreets. So I get next code:

```
private loadStreets(district: District){
    this.addressService.getStreets(district)
      .subscribe(streets => {
        this.streets = streets;
        this.sendStreets.emit(streets);
      });
  }
```

Here everything works fine, because I send streets after I get street from back-end.